# Wordpress: Replacing source(domain name) links

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I'm trying to replace the source link in a wordpress site, its a old site, I've installed it on my local server but all the source files css, js link to domain.com/css/, domain.com/js/

I can't even login to the backend, it redirects to domain.com/wp-admin, I've tried replacing all instances of domain.com, http://domain.com/ in database and wordpress files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: *"source link"* ?  You mean domain name?

Comment: There could be a number of reasons for this.. check your htaccess file, check that your wordpress theme doesn't have the domain.com for the files etc.

Comment: How did you update the database?  If you don't do it properly (eg PHP-serialized values need string lengths updated as well as the text), it probably won't work.  Start with the Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: Thank you Hobo. I've found useful info here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the wp-config.php file to see if the domain's url has been defined in there as described here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

You're looking for:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

If its not defined there, you can put those two lines of code in to change the domain name to whatever you need, it will overwrite the domain name defined in the wordpress admin > general.